# Remeshing algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, triangulation

I need an algorithm to re-triangulate a given 3D solid object.

Input: A triangular mesh
Output: A new triangular mesh where the triangles - as far as possible - have equal edge lengths. Some tolerance is allowed.

Currently I reflect on a clustering algorithm in order to distribute points
equally over the surface. Then I could use a 2D Delaunay triangulation and
project the triangles to the surface. But this is just a vague idea, not an
algorithm. It would be great if somebody could suggest an algorithm or a 
reference to related scientific work.

Answer (score 1):

CGAL provides a surface meshing algorithm that can be used for remeshing.
The documentation page is [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Surface_mesher/Chapter_main.html).

You can directly try it in the demo. On windows precompiled demo is available [here](http://www.cgal.org/demo/4.0.2/polyhedron_3.zip). You'll also need the following [dll's](http://www.cgal.org/demo/4.0.2/CGAL-demoDLLs.zip).

References to scientific publications are available on the aforementioned page.